# Python Selenium Unable to find field element to send _keys

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, discogs-api

[Overlay or Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jox3k.png)I am trying to use Python code in order to update my Discogs with tracking numbers in the specific field when I ship an item.

When I inspect that field box , this is the code (which is also shown in my attachment)

```
input type="text" class="full_width push_down_mini" style="margin-right:0;" placeholder="Tracking number (optional)" data-reactid=".0.$=1$react-modal-overlay.$react-modal.3.0.3"
```

I have been good with using `driver.find_element_by_ID`  `Text` and `Name` to navigate. But can't find out what to use to get this field box element to be located so I can then use `search.send_keys`. I have tried `xpath` & `class` but no luck error comes back with unable to find element.

[Screenshot of Discogs field and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POlPY.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `input` field having multiple class name, namely *`full_width`* and *`push_down_mini`*. So css selector I think is the best approach.

In this case you can't use **`.find_element_by_class_name`**, because this is just for single class name.

**#UPDATE**

Try the below code, use **`.find_element_by_css_selector`**:

```
#update here
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id('onetrustIabCookie'))

search = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.full_width.push_down_mini')
search.send_keys('your key')
```

Or with **`.find_element_by_xpath`**:

```
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class="full_width push_down_mini" and contains(@placeholder, "Tracking number")]')
search.send_keys('your key')
```

Comment: Hello when trying find_element_by_css_selector, i get this error in return : selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61) . As for xpath error: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: @JayBoj is there `<iframe>` tag on the page? Or if possible please share site url.

Comment: Hello, well the page I am reference requires a "seller" to log in so if you dont use Discogs i will be tough to replicate the envrionment. However the URL is this https://www.discogs.com/sell/order/1401942-1884 where 1401942-1884 is specific to the seller & order number, so that can always change. However what I do notice when clicking Mark As shipped and you get the window I put in the attachment with field the URL doesnt change.It seems there is an "over lay" or working within a frame.my attachment link ended up right at the beginning of my post ("overlay or frame")

Comment: Yes there are, the one that is above the field element is :  <iframe id="onetrustIabCookie" title="OneTrust IAB Cookie" src="https://cookies.onetrust.mgr.consensu.org/?name=euconsent&amp;value=&amp;expire=0&amp;isFirstRequest=true" style="display: none;"></iframe>

Comment: And also under that iframe there is a div class react-modal status-change-modal , which identifies that whole box (which contains the field I want to input the keys / text)

Comment: @JayBoj see the above updated answer, if inside `<iframe>` you need switch it first with **`.switch_to.frame`**, please try and inform again what did go later.

Comment: @JayBoj and please don't post as image, copy the HTML and paste in the question.